# condformat on many columns

Tags: r, formatting

I need to use condformat to bold and bgfill >100 columns.
The documentation says I should call the columns by name -- this is a database export where I won't always know the column header names.

It would be great if I can format Bold for each cell value of "YES" in the whole dataset

```
condformat(df[,]) %>%
  rule_text_bold(c(key1), key1== "YES") %>%
  rule_text_bold(c(key2), key2== "YES") %>%
  ...
  ..
  .
```

Any way I can do this without writing a for loop? ...what would a for loop look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your data frame looks something like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
text <- replicate(10,sample(c("YES", "NO"), 10, prob =  c(0.3, 0.7), replace = TRUE))

df <- setNames(as.data.frame(text), paste0("Var", 1:10))
df
#>    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10
#> 1    NO  YES   NO   NO  YES   NO   NO   NO   NO   YES
#> 2   YES   NO   NO  YES   NO  YES   NO  YES   NO   YES
#> 3    NO  YES   NO   NO   NO  YES   NO  YES   NO    NO
#> 4   YES   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO  YES  YES    NO
#> 5    NO   NO   NO   NO   NO  YES   NO   NO  YES    NO
#> 6   YES   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO  YES  YES   NO    NO
#> 7    NO   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO  YES    NO
#> 8   YES   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO   NO  YES    NO
#> 9    NO   NO   NO   NO   NO  YES  YES   NO   NO    NO
#> 10   NO  YES   NO   NO   NO  YES  YES  YES  YES    NO
```

Then you can simply loop along the columns applying your changes like this:

```
library(condformat)

df2 <- condformat(df)

for(i in 1:10) df2 <- rule_text_bold(df2, eval(names(df2)[!!i]), df2[[!!i]] == "YES")
```

You can't display an html table in stack overflow, so here it is as a grob:

```
condformat2grob(df2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Allan, thank you! This worked so well! Do you know the best way to export this formatting to .xls? Where it's not a written conditional formatting rule, but actual cell formatting?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create a string with `paste` and then `eval`uate

```
library(condformat)
data(iris)
nm1 <- names(iris)[1:4]
eval(parse(text= paste('condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),])  %>%', 
     paste("rule_text_bold(", nm1, ', Species == "setosa")', collapse="%>%"))))
```

-output

[image]